# Invalid Element in SOAP Request

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I auto-generated a solution from a WSDL file for a project I'm working on, but for some reason the solution does not seem to correctly handle the input specified by the WSDL. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Given the following operation:

```
<wsdl:operation name="createBin">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:createBinRequest" name="createBinRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="impl:createBinResponse" name="createBinResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:message name="createBinRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="impl:createBin" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<element name="createBin">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="request" type="impl:Bin"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
<complexType name="Bin">
    <sequence>
        <element name="FulfillerID" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
        <element name="BinID" nillable="true" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
        <element name="ExternalLocationID" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="BinType" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="BinStatus" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="Name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Implemented with this code (auto-generated by eclipse):

```
public PositiveInteger createBin(Bin request) throws RemoteException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

When sending this message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://my.api.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <q0:createBin>
            <q0:request>
                <q0:FulfillerID>1234</q0:FulfillerID> 
                <q0:BinID>1234</q0:BinID> 
                <q0:ExternalLocationID>1234</q0:ExternalLocationID> 
                <q0:BinType>Good</q0:BinType> 
                <q0:BinStatus>Bad</q0:BinStatus> 
                <q0:Name>Ugly</q0:Name> 
            </q0:request>
        </q0:createBin>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get the following error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode> 
            <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.api.my.Bin - request</faultstring> 
            <detail>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">localhost</ns1:hostname> 
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm 100% sure that the SOAP message is the correct format, so my server must be choking on something. When I remove the  parameter, everything works swimmingly for some reason.

I can however, get the expected behavior by removing the  element like so:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://my.api.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <q0:createBin>
            <q0:FulfillerID>1234</q0:FulfillerID> 
            <q0:BinID>1234</q0:BinID> 
            <q0:ExternalLocationID>1234</q0:ExternalLocationID> 
            <q0:BinType>Good</q0:BinType> 
            <q0:BinStatus>Bad</q0:BinStatus> 
            <q0:Name>Ugly</q0:Name> 
        </q0:createBin>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Having the `createBin` method throwing an unspecified exception like `UnsupportedOperationException` might result in an 'unspecified' soap fault. What do you expect?

Comment: Call me crazy, but I expected an `UnsupportedOperationException`, not a `SAXException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the SAX parser is not interpreting the request that it looks like it should. Even though the parameter to the method is `request`, it ignores that and expects to parse an element that has a `request` field of type `com.api.my.Bin`. The problem was fixed by changing .

```
public PositiveInteger createBin(Bin request) throws RemoteException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

With

```
public PositiveInteger createBin(CreateBin request) throws RemoteException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Where

```
public class CreateBin {
    public Bin request;

    /* ... */
}
```

Though, to be transparent, I did have to do a lot of tweaking to the `CoreServiceSoapBindingStub` and `CoreServiceSoapBindingSkeleton` that eclipse generated in order to get the whole thing not to blow up because of invalid something-or-other.

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching my brain to remember where I saw this before, but I'm certain I've seen some seemingly 'invalid SOAP requests' which turned out to be invalid because the response was invalid.

In this light: could you change the generated createBin(Bin request) code to return a `PositiveInteger` rather than `-3`? Maybe if we can make te response valid, your server will stop complaining.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added some more details to the question, but I forgot to mention that I sent a "malformed" request and got back a response with the -3 value (as odd as that is).